# Show Warning Message in Checkout Page based on Quantity (Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add a warning message on the Checkout Page in case the products have a quantity greater than 1.

I tried to change this code, but it only works for the cart page.

```
function display_notice_based_on_item_quantity() {

       foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {    
            if ( $cart_item['quantity'] > 1 )
            {
                if ( is_cart() )
                    wc_print_notice( sprintf( __("there is an item with qunatity greater than 1 in the cart", "woocommerce") ), 'notice' );
                break;
            }
       } 

    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'display_notice_based_on_item_quantity' );
```

I would only need to have it for the Checkout Page. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I typically use these two hooks:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'your_function_here');
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'your_function_here', 2);
```

You can still use your cart foreach since it'll work on the cart and checkout pages...